# Is .mp3 audio sufficient for iOS apps or you need .ogg as well?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, mp3, core-audio

For an app built with Cordova, do I need both .ogg and .mp3 files in order the audio to run on iPhone and iPad?

The ex-developer working on the project said all audio files must be included in both formats as some phones can't play one of them.

I recently read that iOS even can't play .ogg.

So is it possible that I need both files just for Android, but for iOS I am fine with .mp3 only?

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine with mp3 only. That's what I do here and I have no issues with neither Android and iOS.